# How can I edit a specific item on my website's front page on Magento

Tags: magento

I would like to get some help with finding a particular item that shows in my website's homepage. I'm trying to edit the page source code by using Bluehost online File Manager. The thing is I couldn't find the specific page where I can find the relevant code to edit. I bought this website source code from a company that installed it on the servers and now I want to edit inside stuff by myself.

Comment: You bought the source code of Magento?

Answer (score 1):

There is no single file responsible so put the file manager away. Mostly the front page content is controlled from the administration in the menu CMS > Pages. Look for "Homepage" in the list that shows and click it to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin side:
Catalog->manage products.

Select product then click on it. Then you are able update the info related to this product.